# div that sticks to the top when you scroll past it in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

For example...the new facebook activity stream on the right.  Or on okay cupid (the message/rating dialogue).

How does this work exactly. Can someone point me to a tutorial or explanation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some Javascript to set position: fixed; top: 0px; when $(window).scrollTop() reaches the $("#element_id").offset().top.

Google does a similar thing with their new gmail look

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do this but here is one using CSS only

```
<div style="position:fixed; left:0; top:0; height:100px; width:100%">Stuck to Top</div>
```

Here is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2kmQe/

Comment: hmm, this seems to be basically fixed positioning.  I want it so that the element is placed in the page normally, and only "sticks" to the top when you scroll past it, if that makes sense.

Comment: @weckersham  ... sorry about that but you may want to repost the new details to your question for others to see and assist with.